# Intent not working - Activity not found

Tags: java, android, android-intent, manifest

I have three intents to switch layouts etc.

Only the first seems to work and the other two are from what I can see, identical. I don't know if I have been staring at this for too long now and I am missing something stupid. Any suggestions?

Before anyone says, I've changed the actual package name etc to com.mysite.myapp.  The originals are all spelt as I need them to be.

From my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button general1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btngeneral);
            general1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent("com.mysite.myapp.general");
                    startActivity(i);                   
                }
            });

        Button health1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnhealth);
            health1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent("com.mysite.myapp.health");
                    startActivity(i);                   
                }
            });

        Button navi1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnnavi);
            navi1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent("com.mysite.myapp.navi");
                    startActivity(i);                   
                }
            });
```

The first one there works totally fine as expected it should.

This is from my manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.mysite.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".general"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mysite.myapp.general" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".health"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mysite.myapp.health" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".navi"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mysite.myapp.navi" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The class of the working intent

```
    public class general extends MainActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.general);
        }
}
```

The classes of the two non working intents

```
    public class health extends MainActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.health);
        }
}
```

and

```
    public class navi extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navi);
    }

}
```

I hope someone has some good suggestions as I've been staring at this now for far too long.

Comment: package names for activities are same?

Comment: please post how you declared all your Activities package names and package name of your application...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check your Application package (the package name that you declared in manifest) and all Activities package names are same... if yes, your code should work. if no, declare your Activities in manifest with fully qualified package  name

if not yet, try this (give least preference to below way)

replace

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.mysite.myapp.general");
startActivity(i);
```

with

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,general.class);
startActivity(i);
```

and do change for other things also

Comment: I don't understand the real difference in the two but the second worked. Any chance on an explanation how what I did doesn't work. Or is that just not the way to do it?

Comment: @Slugshead check this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html explicit intents vs implicit intents. Explicit intent is what you should use.

Comment: @Raghunandan and **new Intent(String)** , here String parameter represents a action, not the package name

Comment: @GopalRao nope check implicit intent vs explicit intents in the docs. what op has is implicit

Comment: @Raghunandan you are right... really thanks for guiding me.I have not seen that he has declared intent filters manifest... and you can downvote this answer and post the better answer for it. may be user has different package name for Activities... any way thanks once again...

Comment: @GopalRao i am not downvoting as it is not entirely wrong. Should use explicit intent. yes in op's case it may be a problem with package name. You edit your post and ask the question poster to check the edit. I have pointed out upto you to edit it now.

Answer (score 0):

Change code with following

```
   Intent i = new Intent(this, general.class);
   startActivity(i);
```

And like-wise for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Each activity should extend just `Activity` not your `MainActivity`. In Android, activities live as their own standalone entities. Call them `NaviActivity`, `HealthActivity` and `GeneralActivity`

Also, remove the intent filters from your manifest, you don't need them and should start the activities with

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NaviActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```